# Java REST API upon building string after get request replace null values with string vale

Tags: java, json, string, replace, null

I am currently working on a Java application where I have an AsyncTask function get data from an API, then have a line reader and string builder create a large string, which I then pass to the postExecute function where I convert that string into a JSON object. I have tried creating a function that takes the string before post execute and replaces all null with "N/A", I have also tried checking in the String builder function but neither seem to make any changes to the null value. Here is an example of what the code looks like. I believe the error occurs when The string is converted into the JSON Object. This is a school project and I am not allowed to use external libraries.

String Builder:

```
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpClient.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (line.contains(null) || line.contains(""))
                            line += "N/A";
                        else
                            continue;
                        builder.append(line + "\n");
                    }
```

replaceNull Function:

```
    public String removeUnwantedVal(String message) {
        if (message.contains("null")) {
            String replacement = "N/A";
            message.replaceAll(null, replacement);
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Post Execute JSON Object:

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.display);
            System.out.println(message);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonAddress = new JSONObject(message);

//                DISPLAY INFORMATION
                String requesterIP = jsonAddress.getString("requester-ip");
                String execTime = jsonAddress.getString("execution-time");
                ipInfo.setIPAndTime(requesterIP, execTime);

//                GEOGRAPHY
                JSONObject geo = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("geo");
                String countryName = geo.getString("country-name");
                String capital = geo.getString("capital");
                String iso = geo.getString("country-iso-code");
                String city = geo.getString("city");
                double longitude = geo.getDouble("longitude");
                double latitude = geo.getDouble("latitude");
                location = new Location(countryName, capital, iso, city, longitude, latitude);

//                  CURRENCY
                JSONObject currency = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("currency");
                String currencyNativeName = currency.getString("native-name");
                String currencyCode = currency.getString("code");
                String currencyName = currency.getString("name");
                String currencySymbol = currency.getString("symbol");
                Currency = new Currency(currencyNativeName, currencyCode, currencyName, currencySymbol);

//                  ASN
                JSONObject asn = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("asn");
                String asnName = asn.getString("name");
                String asnDomain = asn.getString("domain");
                String asnOrganization = asn.getString("organization");
                String asnCode = asn.getString("asn");
                String asnType = asn.getString("type");
                ASN = new ASN(asnName, asnDomain, asnOrganization, asnCode, asnType);

//                  TIMEZONE
                JSONObject timezone = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("timezone");
                String timezoneName = timezone.getString("microsoft-name");
                String dateTime = timezone.getString("date-time");
                String ianaName = timezone.getString("iana-name");
                Timezone = new Timezone(timezoneName, dateTime, ianaName);

//                  SECURITY
                JSONObject security = jsonAddress.getJSONObject("security");
                boolean isCrawler = security.getBoolean("is-crawler");
                boolean isProxy = security.getBoolean("is-proxy");
                boolean isTor = security.getBoolean("is-tor");
                Security = new Security(isCrawler, isProxy, isTor);

                container = new IPContainer(ipInfo, Currency, location, Security, ASN, Timezone);
                tv.setText(container.displayGeneral());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                tv.setText(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. When I was getting the code I thought that null values could not be displayed, this was incorrect. The problem was that I was trying to create an object out of null, sometimes the value came back as null instead of as an object. Sorry, beginner coder :)